# GUI Style Examples

Tags: html, css

Are there any site that show good examples of web application styles? Form designs and layout styles?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522856/what-are-good-resources-for-css-templates-or-templated-layout-sites and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at these articles:

- [10 Useful Web Application Interface Techniques](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/12/10-useful-web-application-interface-techniques/)
- [10 Useful Techniques to Improve Your User Interface Designs](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/12/15/10-useful-techniques-to-improve-your-user-interface-designs/)

They not only provide examples of good layouts, but explain *why* the layouts are good, and have tips and design ideas on how to make your web applications easy to use.

The first link focuses more on general points to make your layouts more user-friendly, whilst the second hones in more specific techniques to improve your designs.

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) also has a plethora of well-written articles related to design and content; the [design](http://www.alistapart.com/topics/design/) section has a lot of articles that relate to layout and design.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the many tutorials and examples on http://www.w3schools.com/ ?

There is always http://www.csszengarden.com/ that shows how you can manipulate the content of your web page just by altering the style sheet.

You can find a large list of examples of form designs at:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/04/17/web-form-design-modern-solutions-and-creative-ideas/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the direction you want to go, but a couple of VERY nice designs can be found on [CSSMania](http://cssmania.com/) and [TemplateMonster](http://www.templatemonster.com/).

One note on that: Getting good design and usability at the same time is an art in itself :) (google basically comes without any particular design and has its fair share of users)

Comment: I've also found similar designs at http://www.templates24x7.com

Answer (score 0):

There is a great collection of design patterns for various webdesign elements on Flickr:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/factoryjoe/collections/72157600001823120/

Answer (score 0):

This site is devoted to user experience and has a very large showcase of interface examples:
http://konigi.com/interface/tags

Answer (score 0):

Smashing Magazine has some useful links ... a few have been mentioned in previous responses, so I will add the one that I have found useful ...

[40 Helpful Resources On User Interface Design Patterns](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/)